# django forms - change the value of the fields

Tags: django, forms, model

I have these models

```
class Student(Model):
    student_no = CharField(max_length=10)
    name = CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ClassList(Model):
    students = ForeignKey(Student)
```

In forms:

```
class ClassListForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        fields = ['students']
```

When I render this, the template shows a select box with the students in it. However, the students are displayed based on what the `def __str__()` function contains. How do you change the values of the `students` field so that it will display their `student_nos` without changing the `def __str__()` function

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property:

```
class Student(Model):
    student_no = CharField(max_length=10)
    name = CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def _get_student_no(self):
        return self.student_no

    get_student_no = property(_get_student_no)
```